# MySQL duplicate entry error even though there is no duplicate entry(Spark)

Tags: mysql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am using Apache Spark to write the same dataframe into HDFS and MySQL.

MySQL insertion-

```
renamedDF.write.option("truncate", "true").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("batchsize", mysqlBatchSize).jdbc(mysqlConnectionUrl + mysqlBatchInsertOptimisationKey, mysqlTable, conf)
```

HDFS insertion

```
renamedDF.write.format(CommonConstants.OUTPUT_CSV_FORMAT).option("emptyValue","").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)
```

the final count of both of them is same

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domain_adformat_rank_info;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1704041 |
+----------+
```

```
scala> df.count

res0: Long = 1704041
```

but if I apply a filter condition and check the entries then the output is different

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM domain_adformat_rank_info_bkp27_Oct WHERE domain = "yahoo.com" AND dc_name = "AMS";
```

| dc_name | domain | adformat | 30_day_gecpm | 1_day_gecpm | 7_day_gecpm | 30_day_rank | 7_day_rank | 1_day_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMS | yahoo.com | 1 | 0.01164206037941487 | 0.019982212949069277 | 0.013386510412446496 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

`val df=spark.read.csv("/tmp/finalDFPath_opparts1")`

```
scala> df.filter(col("_c1")==="yahoo.com" and col("_c0")==="AMS").show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|_c6|_c7|_c8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I tried to change the output savemode and also restricting the number of output partitions by coalescing the dataframe, but they did not work.